# how to use html5 canvas drag on android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to use a WebView with a canvas, and to be able to use touch to drag items in the canvas. The canvas is displayed just fine, and clicking works, but moving only scrolls. I've disabled scrolling, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you disable scrolling? Which events are you handling to detect the drag attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found working html here
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/55121/html5-canvas-drawing-in-webview
It appears that I need to learn more about the difference between touch events and mouse events.